# Fetch and play video stream from Web Socket

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to fetch a video stream that is sent from a third-party webserver and played in a HTML5 video tag. The video tag of the third-party HTML file looks like this:

```html
<video preload="none"
data-current-player="true" playsinline="true"
webkit-playsinline="true" id="video-player"
class="videoPlayer--1OifI"        
src="blob:https://test.com/351a928a-f2db-4d0b-b309-0af2485ad29c">
</video>
```

The video itself is split up into multiple BLOB files. I can receive them by opening a Websocket like this:

```js
 // Open a connection
        var socket = new WebSocket('wss://test.com/websocketstream?videoSessionId=nek34');

        // When a connection is made
        socket.onopen = function () {
            console.log('Opened connection ');
            // send data to the server
            var json = JSON.stringify(
                {
                    eventType: "PLAY",
                    requestId: 23,
                }
            );
            socket.send(json);
        };

       // When data is received
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var blob = null;
            if(event.data instanceof Blob)       {
                blob = event.data;
            }  else if(event.data == typeof "string"){
                blob = new Blob([event.data])
            } 
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        };
```

Now I'm stuck since I don't know what I should do with the BLOB files to merge and convert them to a video stream. Is it possible to convert this BLOB stream to an mp4 stream?
If this doesn't work, is it possible to get the video stream somehow from the browser's cache?

Comment: Media Source Extensions is what you're looking for... but this is a really wonky way to get your video.  Why go through the overhead of Web Sockets when normal HTTP would work just fine?

Comment: @Brad Well, as I said the provider streams his video via a web socket. How would I receive the video on my side without a web socket?